# postgresql count number of employees per year

Tags: database, postgresql, count, pgadmin

Columns: id, first_name, last_name, start_date, end_date
NULL allowed only in end-date.

This works for showing how many people **started** in a particular year:

```
SELECT
  to_char(date_trunc('year', start_date)::date, 'YYYY') AS "Year",
  COUNT(*) AS "New Employees"
FROM employees 
GROUP BY date_trunc('year', start_date)
ORDER BY date_trunc('year', start_date) ASC
```

I cannot find a solution to display a list of years with the **total number** of employees in a particular year.
The assumption is that e.g. in 2022 I would count those with end_date = null AND end_date = 2022.

Comment: why you want to do this "I cannot find a solution to display the number of people hired in a particular year." when you already achieve this "This works for showing how many people were hired in a particular year"

Comment: The condition `end_date = NULL AND end_date = 2022` is not possible. What is the question you're trying to answer? Is it "How many employees were hired in a given year?"  I suggest not casting any date or time data types to strings unless you have a really good reason. Never store date or times as strings in the DB. It seems like you're close with what you have already.

Comment: You can use EXTRACT() to get a certain part from a date, like the year: EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)

Comment: What I have pasted before shows a list of years and the number of employees who started in a particular year. I am trying to come up with another view showing a list of years and the total number of employees in a particular year. 
The first view would show that in 2020 we had 5 new employees, in 2021 we had 3 new employees, etc. 
The second view would show that in 2020 we had 50 employees in total, in 2021 we had 60 employees, etc. 
Employees with end_date=NULL are current employees as well as employees with end_date=2010 would still be considered current workers in 2010 but not in 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of all relevant years, that is to say, all years from the earliest starting date until the current year. Then count the number of active employees for each year.

PostgreSQL provides the useful [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function for creating the range of years. You can use [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to replace an empty `end_date` with the current date, available from [current_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). The resulting query is

```
with years(year) as (
  select generate_series(
    date_trunc('year', (select min(start_date) from employees)),
    date_trunc('year', current_date),
    interval '1 year'
  )
)
select to_char(year, 'yyyy') as year, count(*)
from years
join employees on start_date < year + '1 year'
  and coalesce(end_date, current_date) >= year
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.